# In sqlite query how to get a specific row and column that has the required value

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I am trying to build a quiz app and the entries in the database look like this

```
id | term | synonym 1 | synonym 1 answered | synonym 2 | synonym 2 answered | ....
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | read | recite    |       Yes          | study     |     No             |
2  | work | effort    |       No           | labour    |     Yes            |
```

The idea is to present one synonym at a time. Once the next synonym is chosen, the previous synonym is marked as answered using the column next to the synonym with "Yes"

For the logic to select a word I am using a Collection.shuffle() function to get a random row and random column, query database to see if its answered column is "No". If "Yes" I am repeating the shuffle till I get a "No".

For knowing if atleast one entry in the entire table has a "No" in any of the 'answered' columns, I am using an OR clause against the answered columns (to make sure that all synonyms are not already answered)

So my app is doing lot of iterations to get the desired word which is definitely very bad way.

I am unable to figure a way to let sqlite query return me a random row and column that has the word "No". If I can get the column name of the result that had "No", I can strip the word 'answered' and get the related synonym column in a row, and present it with out much of java code.

Can any one kindly enlighten me on this and give a solution? I would require the column name and the rowid of the resulting match of a word "No" in the entire table. And it must be at RANDOM

Edit:
The scenario given here is for simplicity. The actual app deals with Sanskrit grammar and requires the kind of implementation I am planning. I require to get the 'name' of the column and 'id' of the row that got a 'No'. In the implementation I won't be using 'Yes' and 'No'. The number of columns would be fixed for all the terms. For simplicity I gave this example.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following:

First normalize your table structure. There will be two tables: `Terms` and `Synonyms`

`Terms` table will have `Id` and `TermName`

In the `Synonyms` table there will be `SynonymId`, `Name`, `Answered` `TermId` So, you can track synonyms through `TermId` here.

This way, you can easily query to see what synonyms are still not answered for a specific term like:

```
SELECT * FROM Synomyms WHERE TermId = 1 AND Answered = "No"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You kind of defined pretty well what I meant that would make more sense, here comes a +1

Comment: The scenario is little different. Your suggestion is good with most situations. But the scenario I am working with on Sanskrit grammar requires the kind of implementation I am planning. I require to get the 'name' of the column and 'id' of the row that got an 'Yes'. In the implementation I won't be using 'Yes' and 'No'. For simplicity I gave this. Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

Well, the yes/no part is a little tedious, especially if you did it that way (to me, another relational table would make more sense, but that's another story).

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
    synonym_1_answered = 'No' 
    OR synonym_2_answered = 'No' 
    OR ...
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Filter the ones with a `"No"` using `where`, and use the `random` function to "sort" (more like unsort) them.

Edit:

Once you're done with the data selection, and provided you have a Cursor pointing to this result, it's as easy as:

```
Long long = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("long"));
boolean is_synonym_1_answered = 
    cursor.getString(
        cursor.getColumnIndex("synonym_1_answered")
    ).equals('Yes');

boolean is_synonym_2_answered = 
    cursor.getString(
        cursor.getColumnIndex("synonym_2_answered")
    ).equals('Yes');
...
```

After that, you only need to check which of the booleans is negative, and thus that synonym hasn't been answered yet. You can speed up things by storing the positions of your query in constants (so `ID` is 0, `TERM` is 1... The typical situation is to store them in an Array). That way you don't waste time asking the cursor for the position of a column:

```
Long long = cursor.getLong(ID);
boolean is_synonym_1_answered = cursor.getString(SYNONYM_1_ANS).equals('Yes');
boolean is_synonym_2_answered = cursor.getString(SYNONYM_2_ANS).equals('Yes');
...
```

Again, to speed up things, a second table containing just a synonym and a reference to the original term would make things way easier (as every row returned by a query like that would be an unchecked synonym).

Comment: How do I get the name of column and rowid from the resuly which had the match? I am using Cursor object (Android). Thanks for your kind attention

Comment: Looks promising..I will implement and get back. Thank you. I know the database normalization has to be done, but the scenario I am working is more complex than what I illustrated. Once I completely get the implementation I can think of normalizing

Comment: @user1134670 Good to know you have that planned. However, in my own experience, trying to change how a database is implemented after the app has been deployed, is a terrible pain. Anyway, good luck!